# Opening a ZIP file freezes my computer for a minute or two

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, freeze

If I download a .zip file (using chrome) and click it *before it downloads* so that it automatically opens when it finishes, my entire computer (except chrome - I can still use chrome) freezes for about 30 seconds.

Even explorer.exe crashes. How do I fix this and what causes it? It seems very specific.

Comment: why are you opening before the download completes? The file is corrupt and will never open if the download is not finished.

Comment: No, it opens when it completes. It's a feature of chrome, it will automatically open when it's done. It still opens fine, it just takes a bit.

Comment: hmmm,was not aware...... filetype? Whats the default application to open file? Will it open correctly when not using Chrome to auto open?

Comment: The filetype is .ZIP files, the default application is windows explorer. And yes, it works fine if I don't have it auto-open. But I *really* like that feature.

Comment: Maybe another extension is interferring. Disable them. Incognito?

Comment: Tried incognito, still does it.

Comment: follow the steps from here ad upload the dumps: http://pastebin.com/HAh45FFJ

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading and installing [7-zip](http://7-zip.org). It will take ownership of the .zip format and should stop Explorer from being the default 'reader' and freezing.

Even if you didn't have this problem I'd still recommend downloading it, it's a great tool!

Comment: I have 7zip but I like explorer better.